# Replace a specific character with a word in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have in my documents fields containing lot of plain text, in which there are some symbols for currencies. How can I change these to corresponding names like $ to dollars etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a custom analyzer with a [mapping char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) in which you specify which character to replace by which other ones:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/my_index -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "currencies": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "$=>USD"               <--- define your currency mappings here
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "currencies"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then if you index a sentence like `You owe me $ 100`, the tokens that will be produced are the following:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty' -d 'You owe me $ 100'

{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "You",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "owe",
    "start_offset" : 4,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "me",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 10,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
    "token" : "USD",
    "start_offset" : 11,
    "end_offset" : 12,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 4
  }, {
    "token" : "100",
    "start_offset" : 13,
    "end_offset" : 16,
    "type" : "<NUM>",
    "position" : 5
  } ]
}
```

As you can see, the `$` sign has been replaced by the string `USD`.